# How can I normalize a list that has entries which are not relevant

Tags: python, list, normalization

I'm extracting information from a K8 and creating a json file. From that file I extract three properties and create a list of Services.

The services may have multiple entries varying in the version. My goal is to remove the older version and keep only the latest version.

```
class Service:
    def __init__(self, app, version, port):
        self.app = app
        self.version = version
        self.port = port

    def __str__(self):
        return 'service: {} version: {} port: {}'.format(
            self.app, self.version, self.port)
```

This function processes the file:

```
def process_file(file):
    services = []
    with open(file, 'r') as handle:
        data = json.load(handle)
        for _, item in enumerate(data['items']):
            app = item['spec']['selector']['app'].lower()
            version = item['spec']['selector']['version']
            for protocol in item['spec']['ports']:
                if protocol['name'] == 'https':
                    port = protocol['nodePort']
                    services.append(Service(app, version, port))
        return services
```

And return the following information:

```
service: accessoryservice version: 1.2.12 port: 31751
service: aktivateuserinterface version: 1.2.198 port: 30265
service: approvalservices version: 1.1.0 port: 30230
service: approvalservices version: 1.2.11 port: 31380
service: cachemanagement version: 1.0.0 port: 31805
service: cachemanagement version: 1.1.0 port: 32678
service: cachemanagement version: 1.2.8 port: 31799
service: cashdrawermgmt version: 1.1.0 port: 32576
service: cashdrawermgmt version: 1.2.4 port: 31905
service: clovertradeupservices version: 1.2.9 port: 30562
service: collateralservice version: 1.0.0 port: 32037
service: collateralservice version: 1.1.0 port: 32244
service: collateralservice version: 1.2.8 port: 31445
service: compatibilityservice version: 1.0.0 port: 31335
service: compatibilityservice version: 1.1.0 port: 32739
service: compatibilityservice version: 1.2.13 port: 32472
service: customerdetails version: 1.0.0 port: 31007
service: customerdetails version: 1.1.2 port: 30209
service: customerdetails version: 1.2.57 port: 30546
```

How can I process this information and remove cachemanagement 1.0.0 and 1.1.0? The goal is to have one version of each service for example cachemanagement 1.2.8 in the list.

Comment: filter the list so it doesn't include those entries. You can use the filter function or just use a loop and build up a new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dictionary instead of a list you can check if the version is newer before adding it.

```
from packaging.version import parse  # used to compare version strings

def process_file(file):
    services = {} # dict
    with open(file, 'r') as handle:
        data = json.load(handle)
        for _, item in enumerate(data['items']):
            app = item['spec']['selector']['app'].lower()
            version = item['spec']['selector']['version']
            for protocol in item['spec']['ports']:
                if protocol['name'] == 'https':
                    port = protocol['nodePort']
                    if app not in services:
                      services[app] = Service(app, version, port)
                    elif parse(services[app].version) < parse(version):  # update service only if version newer
                      services[app] = Service(app, version, port)
        return services
```